# Where do I find a list of Arduino DIY shields

Tags: arduino, cost

I am interested in [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) shields for fun, so I do not have a specific need. To save money, I would like to build the shields myself. Is there somewhere I can see a list of the most common, simple and useful shields? I am interested in:

- Parts cost
- Parts availability
- Buying pre made print boards with no components
- Level of expertise needed to assemble

Comment: You're unlikely to save money buying parts and proto boards to build shields yourself, compared to buying budget versions of the typical designs.  The time to build them yourself would be when you need a different form factor or custom functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a google for "Arduino Shield List" or similar, here are a couple of good links:

Site totally dedicated to Arduino shields and their pinouts:
[shieldlist.org](http://shieldlist.org/)

Arduino compatible hardware:
[List of Compatible Hardware for Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Main/SimilarBoards)

---

To find out about the schematics and parts needed for the shield, it will depend mainly on the shield maker. If you follow the link on the shield page to the makers site, they will usually have this information in varying detail.

I picked a couple of examples at random, the "Danger Shield" from Seeed Studio and the "Ethernet Shield" from Adafruit:

On the shieldlist page, there was a link to a Wiki with "make it" and "use it" headings detailing components and code:
[Danger Shield Wiki](http://wiki.nycresistor.com/wiki/Danger_Shield_1.0)
Also there was a link to the schematics and design files:
[Danger Shield firmware and board design](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dangershield/files/)

Adafuit had "[make it](http://www.ladyada.net/make/eshield/make.html)" and "[use it](http://www.ladyada.net/make/eshield/use.html)" pages along with these downloads:
[Ethernet Shield schematic and library](http://www.ladyada.net/make/eshield/download.html)

Comment: Yes I have already see these pages. Maybe I am mistaken, but it does not seem like they give any of the informations from my list of interests.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen - Sorry, I thought you were also interested in a general list of the shields. I think you will have to follow the links to get the detailed info from the maker. I added a couple of examples. Since most of the shields are open source the information is usually quite easy to come by.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in putting your own circuits on a bare shield (assuming you don't want to make your own PCB from scratch), then you should consider one of the many prototype shields, [like this kit](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/protoshield-kit-for-arduino-p-318.html) from [Seeed Studio](http://WWW.seeedstudio.com) for under $8

[image]

There are several other boards like this; just Google "prototype shield".